# ASP net 4 search and render the result in modal bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How I input a text into a field and when i click in the button show the result into a modal from bootstrap using MVC? I have the follow class:

```
class VatSearch{
[required]


   public string VatNumber { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]

public PartialViewResult SearchVatPartialView()
{
    return PartialView("SearchVatPartialView");
}
public JsonResult AddUserInfo(SearchVatPartialView model)
{
VatResponse result= new VatResponse(model.country,model.vatnumber)
    return Json(result);
 }
    }
```

And I have the view form result

```
<form id="myForm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
</form>

function addUserInfo() {
 $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("AddUserInfo", "Home")',
     type: 'POST',
     data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
         if (data.result) {
             $(':input', '#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('')
         } else {
             $("#showErrorMessage").append(data.responseText);
         }
     }
 });
 }
```

Comment: what is VatResponse or VarResponse ?

Comment: a varResponse  is a model who retrives de name and address from a webservice.

Comment: what is the code on click event you mentioned in question ?

Comment: function addUserInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddUserInfo", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result) {
                $(':input', '#myForm')
                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                    .val('')
            } else {
                $("#showErrorMessage").append(data.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}

Comment: Where is your `modal`?

Comment: firstly add HttpPost attribute on AddUserInfo method, secondly check what is error in web console if any, then check what data.result has.

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Vat response</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="myForm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
</form>
      </div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>